# Why is my random number html extension method returning the same values? 

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are giving a demo in a couple days and I have to go in and mock-up a lot of our views.  This includes making a lot of fake data, etc.  I figured I would drop in a loop and an extension method that returns random numbers so I don't have to make up this hard-coded data myself.

Here is my view code:

```
<% for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) { %>
  <tr>
    <td class="auditsTableAgencyElement">Agency <%=i %></td>
    <td class="auditsTableResults"><%= Html.GetRandomNumber(0, 30) %></td>
    <td class="auditsTableResults"><%= Html.GetRandomNumber(0, 100) %>%</td>
    <td class="auditsTableResults"><%= Html.GetRandomNumber(0, 20) %></td>

    <% foreach (var record in Model.Categories) { %>
      <td class="auditsTableResults"><%= Html.GetRandomNumber(0, 30) %></td>
      <td class="auditsTableResults"><%= Html.GetRandomNumber(0, 100) %>%</td>
      <td class="auditsTableResults"><%= Html.GetRandomNumber(0, 20) %></td>
    <% } %>
  </tr>
<% } %>
```

Here is what my view looks like after doing this:
[image]

Same numbers down the line.  Are my requests for random numbers getting cached and returned to me?  If so, how do I turn off this functionality for this method only?

```
public static string GetRandomNumber(this HtmlHelper html, int low, int high)
{
  Random myRand = new Random();
  return myRand.Next(low, high).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As ever with this sort of issue, the problem is that you're creating a new `Random` instance on every iteration.

Create a single instance and reuse it repeatedly. You can use a static variable, but that won't be thread-safe. In this particular case, creating a new instance per page would probably be okay. However, you'll still get the same data if two people access the page at the same time.

Ideally, you could create a static random used in a thread-safe way, to create new instances of Random which can then be used without locking within a single thread. For example:

```
public static class RandomFactory
{
    private static Random rng = new Random();
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static Random CreateRandom()
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            return new Random(rng.Next());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your page you could have:

```
// Instance variable
protected readonly Random rng = RandomFactory.CreateRandom();
```

and change your method to:

```
public static string GetRandomNumber(this HtmlHelper html, Random rng,
                                     int low, int high)
{
    return rng.Next(low, high).ToString();
}
```

(I'm not quite sure why you've got `HtmlHelper` at all there, to be honest - you're not using it...)

and finally your mark-up to things like this:

```
<%= Html.GetRandomNumber(rng, 0, 30) %>
```

Comment: Don't I need "this HtmlHelper html", in order for it to be an extension method ?

Comment: Also, you mention having a single static instance isn't thread safe.  Can you explain this for me?  What could possibly happen with a bunch of threads potentially calling next() on that same instance?

Comment: @KingNestor you need that in order for it to be an extension method, but you don't need that to call public static function.

Comment: @KingNestor: If you call Next from multiple threads you can corrupt the internal state of the RNG. Don't do it :)

Answer (score 1):

I refer you to [here](http://xkcd.com/221/):

[image: getRandomNumber]

:-P

</sarcasm>